# Measuring time when using UnitTests with an asynchronous code

Tags: c#, performance, unit-testing, asynchronous, time

I have an asynchronous code in my UnitTest.

**The problem** is that the timer runs until the asynchronous code ends (as I understood, Am I correct?), but I want to measure the time until the synchronous code ends, how can I do that?

Just code to demonstrate the problem:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyFunction_Success()
{
    var bl = new MyBL();
    bl.ExecuteTask();
}

public void ExecuteTask()
{
    SynchronousCode(); //Takes 1 second.
    AsynchronousCode(); //Takes 5 seconds.
    SynchronousCode(); //Takes 1 second.
}
```

Finally I get this result -> 7 seconds.

[image]

I would expect to get the result -> 2 seconds, so that the asynchronous code won't consider. (Obviously, I don't want to remove the asynchronous call).

Comment: Need details about the two functions that you call. Why would an asynchronous function block if it was truly asynchronous? Is there an async void method somewhere?

Comment: If you don't want to consider the async-code, why is it in there? Maybe you really want to test the SynchronousCode? Why do you want to measure time at all? (Some kind of acceptance criterium?)

Comment: @Carsten König The asnyc code is needed for updating some data, I want this code to be in unit tests so it will be as similar as possible to the runtime code, and in the runtime code I have this async calls. The measuring time of the unit test is important because I write it to a log and I want to get the time of the sync code only.

Comment: you need the runtime of the sync at runtime (not test) - so messure the time in your code - and I still don't see **any** unit-test here (you are testing/asserting *nothing* - you just let your code run

Comment: you have to show "AsynchronousCode"

Comment: I highly doubt it is possible what you want to do. That timer runs from the start of your test until the end, it doesn't really have a concept of the different threads.